# Full address of this letter?

Tags: letter, handwriting

This letter was sent from Domburg to Metz in 1895

[image]

Some parts I can read:

> .. Kaiserlichen Bezirks-Praesidenten ....Freiherrn ...

And what would that *Kaiserlichen Bezirks-Praesident* for a person (profession) be?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a decyphering problem. Additional, the chances are very close to zero, that the answers will help anybody else.

Comment: @userunknown: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1275/392 und https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/579/are-questions-on-reading-of-old-handwritings-on-topic sind also überholt? Gibt es einen neueren Stand zu dieser Frage? PS: Die Diskussion sollte besser gleich auf Meta geführt werden...

Comment: @tohuwawohu: Und hast Du die Metadiskussion nicht gelesen, oder inwiefern siehst Du Takkats Kriterium "we will have to take extra care that they are of general interest" erfüllt?

Comment: @userunknown: es freut mich sehr, dass Du von Deiner generellen Position, ein "decyphering problem" sei bereits für sich genommen off-topic, abrückst. Wenn Du mir ein paar Beispiele nennen könntest, wann solche Fragen "of general interest" sind (und wann nicht), können wir dieses Detail gerne weiterdiskutieren.

Comment: @tohuwawohu: Ich bin von gar nichts abgerückt. Ich habe mich lediglich damit abgefunden, dass es eine Mehrheit von 8:1 anders sieht, mit teils abenteuerlichen Begründungen (Spaß am Entschlüsseln von Handschriften, kein anderer Ort böte sich an, ... - ich sollte das wohl auf Meta weiter ausführen). Ich habe nicht die Behauptung aufgestellt, es könne ein über den Einzelfall hinausgehendes Interesse an einer Frage zu Sütterlin geben, daher muss ich sie auch nicht verteidigen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about the last word in the third line, but i think it reads:

> An seine [Hochwohlgeboren](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hochwohlgeboren)
>       den kaiserlichen Bezirks-Praesidenten Herrn Freiherrn
>       von Hammerstein, Ritterhof 2
>       Metz (Lorraine)

So, the letter was sent to [Hans von Hammerstein-Loxten](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_von_Hammerstein-Loxten), at that time Bezirkspräsident/Président du département (= [District President](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezirk_Lothringen#District_Presidents)) of [Lothringen/Lorraine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezirk_Lothringen). As already said, i'm not sure about the address "Ritterhof 2". The *Bezirkspräsidium* itself was situated at the *Regierungsplatz* at Metz, cf. the city map of Metz from "Meyers Großes Konversations-Lexikon" 1905:

http://images.zeno.org/Meyers-1905/I/big/Wm13722a.jpg

[Meyers doesn't list](http://www.zeno.org/Meyers-1905/B/Metz) a street or place named "Ritterhof", so it's quite likely that my reading isn't correct...